# Skyrim FPS drops when close to objects

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, performance, framerate

Skyrim stutters terribly when I'm close to objects. For example, when closely passing trees at the intro scene or next to a bed when indoors. The game runs fine when outside or in the middle of a house.

I’ve tried using minimal graphics and lowering the resolution. I’ve also tried disabling Vsync and mouse acceleration. I’ve tried lowering my monitors refresh rate to 59hz and lastly, I’ve tried overriding the games graphics settings with the Radeon settings, but none of it helped.

I did some benchmarks and tried some other games to ensure my graphics card was working fine, and it was.

I haven’t installed any mods, but I have installed the DawnGuard, HeartFire and DragonBorn DLCs.

I’ve built the computer I’m playing on myself using an AMD FX 6350 CPU and an AMD Radeon RX 470 GPU.

Finally, here are the contents of my SkyrimPrefs.ini file;

```
[General]
fBrightLightColorB=1.0000
fBrightLightColorG=1.0000
fBrightLightColorR=1.0000
iStoryManagerLoggingEvent=-1
bEnableStoryManagerLogging=0
[Imagespace]
bDoDepthOfField=1
iRadialBlurLevel=0
[Display]
iBlurDeferredShadowMask=0
fInteriorShadowDistance=3000.0000
fShadowDistance=2000
iShadowMapResolutionSecondary=1024
iShadowMapResolutionPrimary=2048
iShadowSplitCount=2
iMaxAnisotropy=1
fLeafAnimDampenDistEnd=4600.0000
fLeafAnimDampenDistStart=3600.0000
fTreesMidLODSwitchDist=3600
fGamma=1.0000
fDecalLOD2=1500.0000
fDecalLOD1=1000.0000
fSpecularLODStartFade=200
fShadowLODStartFade=200.0000
fLightLODStartFade=200
iTexMipMapMinimum=0
iTexMipMapSkip=2
iWaterMultiSamples=0
iMultiSample=1
iShadowMode=3
bTreesReceiveShadows=0
bDrawLandShadows=0
bFull Screen=1
iSize H=900
iSize W=1600
fMeshLODFadePercentDefault=1.2000
fMeshLODFadeBoundDefault=256.0000
fMeshLODLevel2FadeTreeDistance=2048.0000
fMeshLODLevel1FadeTreeDistance=2844.0000
fMeshLODLevel2FadeDist=3072
fMeshLODLevel1FadeDist=4096
iScreenShotIndex=2
bShadowMaskZPrepass=0
bMainZPrepass=0
iMaxSkinDecalsPerFrame=0
iMaxDecalsPerFrame=0
bFloatPointRenderTarget=0
sD3DDevice="Radeon (TM) RX 470 Graphics"
bFXAAEnabled=0
iShadowMapResolution=512
fShadowBiasScale=0.5
iShadowMaskQuarter=3
iAdapter=0
iPresentInterval=0
iShadowFilter=3
bShadowsOnGrass=1
bTransparencyMultisampling=0
bDeferredShadows=1
bDrawShadows=1
[Grass]
b30GrassVS=1
fGrassStartFadeDistance=0
fGrassMaxStartFadeDistance=7000.0000
fGrassMinStartFadeDistance=0.0000
[MAIN]
bGamepadEnable=1
bCrosshairEnabled=1
fHUDOpacity=1.0000
bSaveOnPause=1
bSaveOnTravel=1
bSaveOnWait=1
bSaveOnRest=1
fSkyCellRefFadeDistance=150000.0000
[GamePlay]
bShowFloatingQuestMarkers=1
bShowQuestMarkers=1
iDifficulty=0
[Interface]
bDialogueSubtitles=1
bGeneralSubtitles=1
fMouseCursorSpeed=1.0000
bShowCompass=1
[Controls]
fGamepadHeadingSensitivity=1.0000
fMouseHeadingSensitivity=0.0380
bAlwaysRunByDefault=1
bInvertYValues=0
bGamePadRumble=1
bMouseAcceleration=0
bUseKinect=0
[Particles]
iMaxDesired=750
[SaveGame]
fAutosaveEveryXMins=15.0000
[AudioMenu]
fAudioMasterVolume=1.0000
fVal7=1.0000
uID7=0
fVal6=1.0000
uID6=0
fVal5=1.0000
uID5=0
fVal4=1.0000
uID4=0
fVal3=1.0000
uID3=94881
fVal2=0.4000
uID2=466532
fVal1=1.0000
uID1=554685
fVal0=0.8000
uID0=1007612
[Clouds]
fCloudLevel2Distance=262144.0000
fCloudLevel1Distance=32768.0000
fCloudLevel0Distance=16384.0000
fCloudNearFadeDistance=9000.0000
[TerrainManager]
fTreeLoadDistance=12500
fBlockMaximumDistance=75000
fBlockLevel1Distance=25000
fBlockLevel0Distance=15000
fSplitDistanceMult=0.4
bShowLODInEditor=0
[NavMesh]
fObstacleAlpha=0.5000
fCoverSideHighAlpha=0.8000
fCoverSideLowAlpha=0.6500
fEdgeFullAlpha=1.0000
fEdgeHighAlpha=0.7500
fEdgeLowAlpha=0.5000
fTriangleFullAlpha=0.7000
fTriangleHighAlpha=0.3500
fTriangleLowAlpha=0.2000
fLedgeBoxHalfHeight=25.0000
fEdgeDistFromVert=10.0000
fEdgeThickness=10.0000
fPointSize=2.5000
[Trees]
bRenderSkinnedTrees=1
uiMaxSkinnedTreesToRender=20
[Decals]
uMaxDecals=0
bDecals=0
bSkinnedDecals=0
uMaxSkinDecals=0
uMaxSkinDecalsPerActor=0
[LOD]
fLODFadeOutMultObjects=2.5
fLODFadeOutMultItems=1
fLODFadeOutMultActors=2.5
fLODFadeOutMultSkyCell=1.0000
[Launcher]
bEnableFileSelection=1
bShowAllResolutions=1
uLastAspectRatio=3
[BlurShaderHDR]
bDoHighDynamicRange=0
[BlurShader]
bUseBlurShader=0
[Water]
iWaterReflectHeight=512
iWaterReflectWidth=512
bUseWaterDisplacements=1
bUseWaterRefractions=1
bUseWaterReflections=1
bUseWaterDepth=1
```

Does anyone know how I can get my game working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By now, I've found out that the problem was caused by Skyrim's incompability with Windows 10. If I run the game in Windows 7 compatibility mode, everything works fine.